# Possible to pull list of events with end_time later than today?

Tags: php, facebook, api, events, facebook-graph-api

Using graph API:

```
$events = $facebook->api('/165840163448967/events?since='. time());
```

Gets all events with a start_time later than today. However if an event started on a previous date but continues past today it is not returned.

These events show on facebook as 'Ongoing'

I could obviously just get the last month of events and filter them myself:

```
$events = $facebook->api('/165840163448967/events?since='. (time() - 2419200));
```

but it doesn't seem like the correct way to do things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
$events = $facebook->api('/165840163448967/events?since=today');
```